# Sorting and updating Objects by a value of it's children

Tags: javascript, object

I have JavaScript Object that contains multiple Objects, of which, one the properties is a sortOrder. What is the most efficient method to update the all of the values when one Objects sortOrder is updated.

The parent is an object that contains the children object, like so:

```
parent.children = Object{11: Object, 12: Object, 13: Object}
```

The Children object is structure like so:

```
11: Object
      sortOrder : "1"

12 : Object  
      sortOrder : "2"

13 : Object 
      sortOrder : "3"
```

So if I say update Object 13 sortOrder to 2 then It would look like this:

```
11 : Object
      sortOrder : "1"

12 : Object  
      sortOrder : "2"

13 : Object 
      sortOrder : "2"
```

But I need to update the sibling objects to reflect the new sortOrder, so like this:

```
11 : Object
      sortOrder : "1"

12 : Object  
      sortOrder : "3"

13 : Object
      sortOrder : "2"
```

Or conversely if I updated Object 11 sortOrder to 3 then the other children would need to be reordered like so:

```
11: Object
      sortOrder : "3"

Object 12 : 
      sortOrder : "1"

Object 13 :
      sortOrder : "2"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing the children as an array (a structure that both has the concept of order and has a sorting method)?

Comment: If you want efficient updates you would need a dynamic search tree structure for log n operations such as avl or red black tree

Comment: Order of Object children is not guaranteed so sorting it doesn't make much sense. I would use an array of `Object.keys()`, then sort it based on values in children, then use the sorted keys to do something with the children in particular order.

Comment: The child objects are passed into the parent object as objects, they hold more than just the sortOrder but that is the value I'm trying to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Added description.

You only need to modify values that are in the range between the current sortOrder of the element you intend to change, and the intended new sortOrder for it, so we calculate that range (low & high), and then modify the corresponding elements, and lastly, update the sortOrder of the target element.

```js
var parent = {children: {
  11: {sortOrder: "1"},
  12: {sortOrder: "2"},
  13: {sortOrder: "3"},
  14: {sortOrder: "4"}
}};

function setSortOrderOfChildAt(key, newSortOrder){
  var child = parent.children[key];
  var childOrder = Number(child.sortOrder);
  var low = Math.min(childOrder, newSortOrder);
  var high = Math.max(childOrder, newSortOrder);
  for(var childKey in parent.children){
    var sibling = parent.children[childKey];
    var siblingOrder = Number(sibling.sortOrder);
    // assumes sortOrder is unique, this condition is equivalent to "if sibling !== child"
    if(sibling.sortOrder !== child.sortOrder){
      if(siblingOrder >= low && siblingOrder <= high){
        sibling.sortOrder = "" + (siblingOrder + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  child.sortOrder = "" + newSortOrder;
}

console.log('initial:', parent.children);
console.log('update Object 13 sortOrder to 2:');
setSortOrderOfChildAt(13, 2);
console.log(parent.children);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `old` be the original sort order of the child initially changing.

Let `nu` be the new sort order it is changing to.

Loop through each child:

- If the current child is the one whose sort order is initially changing, then do it, i.e. change its sort order to the new value, `nu`.
- Otherwise, if the sort order of the current child is between `nu` and `old` then either:

  - decrement it if `nu > old` or
  - increment it if `nu < old`.

The algorithm uses absolute value and sign to do this in a concise way.

```js
var parent = {children: {
  11: {sortOrder: "1"},
  12: {sortOrder: "2"},
  13: {sortOrder: "3"},
  14: {sortOrder: "4"}
}};

function setSortOrderOfChildAt(key, nu) {
  var pc = parent.children;
  var old = +pc[key].sortOrder;
  var diff = nu - old;
  for (var c in pc) {
    var curr = +pc[c].sortOrder;
    pc[c] = {sortOrder: (+c === key ? nu : (curr - (
      Math.abs((curr - nu) + (curr - old)) <= Math.abs(diff) ? Math.sign(diff) : 0
    ))).toString()};
  }
}

console.log('initial:', parent.children);
console.log('update Object 13 sortOrder to 2:');
setSortOrderOfChildAt (13, 2);
console.log(parent.children);
```